# How do I link the node module correctly in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have ran `npm install @ant-design/react-native --save` but I keep getting the error below:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-native-community/viewpager` 
from `node_modules/@ant-design/react-native/lib/carousel/index.js`:
@react-native-community/viewpager could not be found within the project.
```

Why is happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to install as `npm i @react-native-community/viewpager`?

Comment: Yeah, very simple, very usefull, thank you!